# How to insert a specific number of newlines in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, text-editing, newlines, insert

Inside org-mode, RETURN is bound to `(org-return &optional INDENT)`. This command apparently ignores `C-u` numeric prefixes and so if you want to enter 10 newlines, you can't just type `C-u 1 0 RET` and have it work. You can do `C-u 1 0 M-x newline` and get expected behavior, but I would like to know if there's a simpler set of default keystrokes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to insert newlines, without any automation for indentation or support for soft newlines, then you can use [`quoted-insert`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Inserting-Text.html#index-quoted_002dinsert-72) (`C-q`), which lets you enter any character including control characters. A newline character is `C-j`, but the <kbd>Return</kbd> key sends `C-m`, so you need to type `C-u 1 0 C-q C-j` (insert a newline, times 10).

If you want to call the [`newline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Inserting-Text.html#index-newline-69) function, you can advise `org-return`. Untested.

```
(defadvice org-return
  (around org-return-prefix-argument (&optional indent arg) activate compile)
  (interactive (list nil current-prefix-arg))
  (letf (((symbol-function 'true-newline) (symbol-function 'newline)
          (symbol-function 'newline) (lambda () (true-newline arg))))
    ad-do-it))
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to advise (or redefine) `org-return` in this case, unless I'm missing something. That's overkill - just define your own command to do what you want, and bind that to `RET`.

Comment: @Drew The point is to use the prefix argument only in the cases when `org-return` would insert a newline, and not affect the other cases (in tables, etc.)

Comment: Is `org-return` used only as a command (not used in Lisp code)? Or if it is used also in Lisp code, should what is requested *not* affect also that code? If so, then why can't you just define a new command to do what you want, and not change `org-return`? The prefix-arg behavior should  not enter into the question of what command to use, but only what the command should do.

Comment: @Drew I didn't check, I think it's only intended for interactive use. I chose to implement a semantics where `C-u RET` in a table would do the same thing as before and ignore the prefix argument. This requires going through the `cond` inside `org-return`. The other semantics where specifying a prefix argument forces the insertion of newlines makes sense and would not call for an advice-based implementation, it's just not what I chose to implement.

Comment: @Gilles `org-return` is used in `org-return-indent` in org.el. But that shouldn't affect it as you added `arg` as the last argument, correct?

Comment: OK. There are certainly many ways to skin a cat! It's probably good to mention such considerations (the things you checked, the things I mentioned, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution:

```
(defun my-org-return (&optional arg indent)
  (interactive "*p")
  (dotimes (number arg) (org-return indent)))
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<return>") 'my-org-return)
```

Comment: This is probably better than the other rebinding since it won't require updating the redefined function with any changes that are made in future releases of org.

Comment: It is always preferable to use your own command instead of advising or redefining another command - *if* you get the desired behavior by doing that, and if other things are equal.

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine `org-return` and `org-return-indent` as follows in your `init.el` (I have redefined the function found in `emacs/24.4/lisp.org/org.el`:

After the redefinition, you can do <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>.

```
(defun org-return (&optional arg indent)
  "Goto next table row or insert a newline.

Calls `org-table-next-row' or `newline', depending on context.
See the individual commands for more information.
With ARG, call `org-return' that many times."
  (interactive "P")
  (let (org-ts-what)
    (cond
     ((or (bobp) (org-in-src-block-p))
      (if indent (newline-and-indent) (newline arg)))
     ((org-at-table-p)
      (org-table-justify-field-maybe)
      (call-interactively 'org-table-next-row))
     ;; when `newline-and-indent' is called within a list, make sure
     ;; text moved stays inside the item.
     ((and (org-in-item-p) indent)
      (if (and (org-at-item-p) (>= (point) (match-end 0)))
          (progn
            (save-match-data (newline arg))
            (org-indent-line-to (length (match-string 0))))
    (let ((ind (org-get-indentation)))
      (newline arg)
      (if (org-looking-back org-list-end-re)
              (org-indent-line)
        (org-indent-line-to ind)))))
     ((and org-return-follows-link
       (org-at-timestamp-p t)
       (not (eq org-ts-what 'after)))
      (org-follow-timestamp-link))
     ((and org-return-follows-link
       (let ((tprop (get-text-property (point) 'face)))
         (or (eq tprop 'org-link)
         (and (listp tprop) (memq 'org-link tprop)))))
      (call-interactively 'org-open-at-point))
     ((and (org-at-heading-p)
       (looking-at
        (org-re "\\([ \t]+\\(:[[:alnum:]_@#%:]+:\\)\\)[ \t]*$")))
      (org-show-entry)
      (end-of-line 1)
      (newline arg))
     (t (if indent (newline-and-indent) (newline arg))))))
```

Note that in `newline-and-indent`, the `ARG` input of `newline` is set to `nil`. So the same is done in the renewed definition of `org-return-indent`.

```
(defun org-return-indent ()
  "Goto next table row or insert a newline and indent.
Calls `org-table-next-row' or `newline-and-indent', depending on
context.  See the individual commands for more information."
  (interactive)
  (org-return nil t))
```

Comment: Why *redefine the command* that `RET` is bound to by default in `org-mode`, instead of just binding `RET` to the command that you want? IOW, it the behavior you code is what is wanted, why not call that command `my-org-return` and bind it to `RET` in `org-mode`?

Comment: @Drew I agree, I made it unnecessary complicated :P

Comment: @Drew Thanks for the nudge; I've added another answer that should do exactly the same as this one. I yet have to venture into using defadvices.

Comment: You can also delete this answer and leave just the other one, if you like. (Or you can leave it, if you think it or the comments are helpful.)