# How to loop zoom-frm-in?

Tags: zooming

Every time I dock/undock I must hit 10 times `M-x` `zoom-frm-in`. Since I don't understand the `dotimes` example in the lisp tutorial I need to know how you would automate this task.

Comment: Would just changing the value of option `frame-zoom-font-difference` help?

Comment: Your [0]answer pointed me to the final solution (see comment there)

[0] https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50803/21118

Answer (score 1):

`(dotimes (number 10) (zoom-frm-in))`

Found here:

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2507/21118

Comment: You can accept your own answer. That will help other users with the same or a similar question.